# How to use cyg-wrapper to fork a new tab in win32 gvim

Tags: vim, cygwin, gvim, bashrc

I would like to set up an alias in my cygwin .bashrc that translates pathnames unix-to-dos and passes them to windows gvim in a new tab of an existing instance. I am trying to use [Luc Hermitte's cyg-wrapper script](http://hermitte.free.fr/cygwin/) for running native win32 applications from Cygwin as per [this vim tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Running_the_win32-version_of_Vim_from_cygwin). Luc's example of how to use his script is:

```
alias vi= 'cyg-wrapper.sh "C:/Progra~1/Edition/vim/vim63/gvim.exe"
    --binary-opt=-c,--cmd,-T,-t,--servername,--remote-send,--remote-expr'
```

I do not understand this example because most of these vim parameters (-c,--cmd,--servername,--remote-send,--remote-expr, etc) require more information, and I have not found any example of how to supply the additional information to cyg-wrapper.sh. For example, calling

```
C:/Progra~1/Edition/vim/vim63/gvim.exe --servername=GVIM 
   --remote-tab-silent file1 &
```

will open file1 in a new tab of existing (or non existing) instance GVIM, but calling `gvim --servername` accomplishes nothing on its own. Unfortunately, though, the corresponding cyg-wrapper phrase does not work:

```
cyg-wrapper.sh "C:/Progra~1/Edition/vim/vim63/gvim.exe"
    --binary-opt=--servername=GVIM,--remote-tab-silent --fork=2 file1
```

If ran twice, this actually opens up two instances of gvim; it is as if the servername 'GVIM' is being stripped and ignored. How do you supply a servername to `gvim --servername` or a .vimrc to `gvim -u` using cyg-wrapper.sh?

Furthermore, why is it that programs must be passed to cyg-wrapper.sh in the relatively obscure "mixed form?" For example, if I try

```
cyg-wrapper.sh "/cygdrive/c/path/to/GVimPortable.exe"
        --binary-opt=--servername=GVIM,--remote-tab-silent --fork=2
```

I get "Invalid switch - "/cygdrive"."

See also:

- [getting-gvim-to-automatically-translate-a-cygwin-path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164181/getting-gvim-to-automatically-translate-a-cygwin-path)
- [alias-to-open-gvim-cream-version-from-cygwin-shell](https://superuser.com/questions/178983/alias-to-open-gvim-cream-version-from-cygwin-shell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to not put the key-value pair options in --binary-opt. The correct way here is:

```
cyg-wrapper.sh "C:/Progra~1/Edition/vim/vim63/gvim.exe" --fork=2 
  --servername=GVIM --remote-tab-silent .bashrc.
```

It is a little bit more complicated when passing in a vimrc. I did not know this, but when passing in a vimrc, the -u parameter must come earlier than other parameters; this:

```
cyg-wrapper.sh "C:/Progra~1/Edition/vim/vim63/gvim.exe" --fork=2 
      --servername=GVIM --remote-tab-silent -u ~/.vimrc file1
```

will actually open up three tabs, one called "-u", one that opens ".vimrc", and one with "file1." To get Cygwin and gvim to open up file1 in a new tab after sourcing a specified .vimrc, you need:

```
cyg-wrapper.sh "C:/Progra~1/Edition/vim/vim63/gvim.exe" --fork=2 
      -u ~/.vimrc --servername=GVIM --remote-tab-silent file1
```

The order of the parameters appears to be important. I may be wrong; I just figured this out experimentally and it isn't mentioned in the GVim documentation, but I think that first come the parameters for cyg-wrapper.sh such as --fork=2, then the single letter parameters for vim such as -u , then the other vim parameters with double hyphens, and finally, the list of files to open.